# What is wrong with my turtle code? Cannot understand

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.8, python-turtle

I was doing a school project about pixelart and wanted to create a landscape.
What is wrong?

```
""" Landscape Drawer.py
    Draws landscape on a turtle screen"""

import turtle as t
import random as r

pen = t.Pen()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed('fastest')

pixelno = 90000

def controls():
    if pen.xcor() == 150 or pen.xcor() == 150 or pen.ycor() == 150 or pen.ycor() == 150:
        pen.right(90)
        pen.forward(1)
        pen.right(90)
        
def allcode():
    while True:
        t.colormode(255)
        controls()
        if pen.ycor() < -75:
            rX = r.randint(0, 150)
            gX = r.randint(0, 255)
            bX = r.randint(0, 150)
            pen.pencolor(rX, gX, bX)
            pen.pendown()
            pen.penup()
            pen.forward(1)
        elif pen.ycor() > -150 or pen.ycor < 150:
            cloud = r.randint(1, 7)
            if cloud == 7:
                pen.pencolor(255, 255, 255)
                t.pendown()
            rY = r.randint(0, 150)
            gY = r.randint(0, 150)
            bY = r.randint(0, 255)
            pen.pencolor(rY, gY, bY)
            pen.pendown()
            pen.penup()
            pen.forward(1)
        else:
            print('Your landscape, look nice? ')
            
            
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-300, -300)
allcode()
pen.exitonclick()
```

P.S. I am using Python 3.8.2.

There are no errors, but the turtle screen is completely blank.

I have actually tried deleting the `pen.hideturtle()` and `pen.speed('fastest')` but it still won't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is riddled with errors:

```
pen.pencolor(255, 255, 255)
t.pendown()
```

Here you're talking to two *different* turtles, your `pen` and the *default* turtle which you haven't touched before now nor ever again.  What's going on here:

```
pen.xcor() == 150 or pen.xcor() == 150
```

is there a minus sign missing?  Ditto for `pen.ycor()`.  These statements are in the wrong order:

```
pen.pendown()
pen.penup()
pen.forward(1)
```

To actually make a mark on the screen you want:

```
pen.pendown()
pen.forward(1)
pen.penup()
```

Look for that error in two places in your code.  This logic:

```
if cloud == 7:
    pen.pencolor(255, 255, 255)
```

is completely undone by what follows next:

```
rY = r.randint(0, 150)
gY = r.randint(0, 150)
bY = r.randint(0, 255)
pen.pencolor(rY, gY, bY)
```

You're missing an `else` clause there.  In this `else` clause:

```
else:
    print('Your landscape, look nice? ')
```

you probably also want a `break` statement otherwise you'll never get out of your infinite `while True:` loop.

Below is my rework of your code to fix the above, but I make no claim that it does anything useful:

```
"""
Landscape Drawer.py
Draws landscape on a turtle screen
"""

from turtle import Screen, Pen
from random import randint

def controls():
    if pen.xcor() == -150 or pen.xcor() == 150 or pen.ycor() == -150 or pen.ycor() == 150:
        pen.right(90)
        pen.forward(1)
        pen.right(90)

def allcode():
    while True:
        controls()

        if pen.ycor() < -75:
            r = randint(0, 150)
            g = randint(0, 255)
            b = randint(0, 150)
            pen.pencolor(r, g, b)

            pen.pendown()
            pen.forward(1)
            pen.penup()
        elif pen.ycor() > -150 or pen.ycor() < 150:
            cloud = randint(1, 7)

            if cloud == 7:
                pen.pencolor(255, 255, 255)
            else:
                r = randint(0, 150)
                g = randint(0, 150)
                b = randint(0, 255)
                pen.pencolor(r, g, b)

            pen.pendown()
            pen.forward(1)
            pen.penup()
        else:
            print('Your landscape, look nice? ')
            break

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

pen = Pen()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed('fastest')

pen.penup()
pen.goto(-300, -300)

allcode()

screen.exitonclick()
```